# Can the integer Heisenberg group be cubulated?

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology

I've been interested in abstract polyhedral decompositions of 3-manifolds for a long time. One thing I've tried to do a lot is to get nice polyhedral decompositions of manifolds with Nil geometry. It has been difficult, however, to find ones without some kind of irregularity (e.g. the boundary graph contains vertices of valence 2).

Cubulation is a strong from of regularity for a group. Can the integer Heisenberg group be cubulated? If so, is there a simple, exact description of nonpositively curved cube complex with fundamental group quasi-isometric to Nil?

Comment: Nil group is not hyperbolic; it is not even semihyperbolic. Thus, integer Heisenberg group cannot be cubulated in any meaningful way.

Comment: Haglund proved something stronger: a discrete group with a proper action on an arbitrary CAT(0) cube complex has no distorted cyclic subgroups. Thus Heisenberg (which has a quadratically distorted $\mathbf{Z}$) has no such proper action.

Comment: Thank you for your answers; in a day or two I will post them as a CW answer to take this off the unanswered questions list, unkess someone else posts an answer.

Comment: PS: about "quasi-isometric to Nil": it follows from Pansu's results that if $G$ is a discrete f.g. group QI to Heisenberg, then it has a finite index subgroup isomorphic to Nil. Thus it also has a distorted $\mathbf{Z}$ and cannot be the fundamental group of a locally CAT(0) cubing, nor even act properly on a CAT(0) cubing.

Comment: It's almost completely sorted out which closed aspherical 3-manifolds are cubulated: this should be true if and only if it admits a non-positively curved metric. There remains only certain graph manifolds which are not NPC (Yi Liu proved they are not virtually special cubulated, but the may still act properly and freely on a CAT(0) cube complex). http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1110.1940

Comment: As has been pointed out, whichever way you look at it the answer is 'no'. (Another obstruction is the Dehn function, which is cubic.  Any CAT(0) group has quadratic Dehn function.) I just want to point out that there are at least two distinct meanings of 'cubulated'---fundamental group of a *compact* npc cube complex, and fundamental group of *any* npc cube complex---and you seem to be working with a third, namely fundamental group of a (compact?) *negatively curved* cube complex, which surely implies word-hyperbolic.  Note that the integer Heisenberg group contains $\mathbb{Z}^2$'s.

Comment: @HJRW I actually meant NPC, but I wrote negatively curved on accident. I'll edit it accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: @HJRW: what do you call *negatively curved* cube complex?

Comment: @Yves I wrote negatively curved on accident in my first post, and he was trying to interpret it.

Comment: @Yves - I don't know!  As Brian says, I was just quoting the question.  I presumed he meant npc with Gromov-hyperbolic universal cover, or something like that.

Comment: ok... but whether every hyperbolic group is CAT(-1) is a big open question, so the use of "negatively curved" for "hyperbolic" is not a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:
A discrete group with a proper action on an arbitrary CAT(0) cube complex has no distorted cyclic subgroups. Thus Heisenberg (which has a quadratically distorted Z) has no such proper action.

It follows from Pansu's results that if G is a discrete f.g. group QI to Heisenberg, then it has a finite index subgroup isomorphic to Nil. Thus it also has a distorted Z and cannot be the fundamental group of a locally CAT(0) cubing, nor even act properly on a CAT(0) cubing.

Another obstruction is the Dehn function, which is cubic. Any CAT(0) group has quadratic Dehn function.

Finally, Nil group is not hyperbolic; it is not even semihyperbolic. Thus, integer Heisenberg group cannot be cubulated in any meaningful way.